# Click button once click just render text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How to create a button than once click the button will render just text by using react hook

```
const WelcomeButton = (props) => {
  
const[welcomeBtn, setwelcomeBtn] = useState()

 const handelClick = () => {
 if() {
 retun <p>Hi John</p>
 }
}
  return (
  <div>
<button onClick={handelClick}> Welcome </button>    
  </div>
  )
  ;
};
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking for, the desired behavior and result. My guess is that you need to update the state in the `onClick` callback and conditionally return the additional JSX in the main function component return as you can't return JSX from an event handler and expect it to just be rendered somewhere.

Comment: Hi there, I just want `<button>Welcome </button>` this button element will disappear once clicked  the button element will be replaced by `<p>Hi John</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a state that tracks that the button has been clicked, and update/toggle this value in the `handleClick` callback. Conditionally render either the button or the welcome text based on this state.

```js
const WelcomeButton = (props) => {
  // initial state true to show button
  const [welcomeBtn, setWelcomeBtn] = React.useState(true);

  const handelClick = () => {
    // toggle false to hide button and display welcome message
    setWelcomeBtn(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {welcomeBtn ? (
        <button onClick={handelClick}> Welcome </button>
      ) : (
        <p>Hi John</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <WelcomeButton />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```